# URL is always on index even though you're in different page

Tags: linux, url, cakephp

I have a website and it always in www.website.com/index even though I am in different page but in my localhost, the URL is changed, my server is LINUX based. I also used cakePHP framework. It happens in Chrome Browser, in Firefox, the URL is changed.

Comment: Please open developer's console in Chrome and see if any error occurs.

Comment: There's no error. It's changing page but the URL is always in index. That's why when I refresh the page, it's going in the login phase. I thought of a solution but I don't know how. Is there a way to get the previous link? So that if the user refreshes the page, the index will redirect the page to the last visited.

Comment: You need to provide some code though.